# When is oracle.net.ns.Packet.recieve() method invoked?

Tags: java, database, oracle, database-design, oracle11g

I have not been able to find documentation of oracle.net.ns.Packet.recieve() method anywehre. Is this method only invoked on select queries ? or is it also invoked on insert update etc. ?

My application is spending majority of it's time in this method. What can I do to improve performance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is invoked when data is being transferred between two processes. The most usual example is when a client is accessing a remote database and performs DML (select, insert, update, delete). Although the method is invoked in all these cases, it should occur with higher frequencies in case of SELECTs.

If the amount of data being transferred over the network doesn't justify the time spent on this method or if the method is invoked too often, you might want to take a look at this document and play with the SDU size:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/performance.htm#NETAG014

If you're running a 10g database, this is the appropriate document:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/network.101/b10775/performance.htm